# Strange error when trying to send email

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, runtime-error

The following strange error is returned. I cannot understand where it's coming from as the Netbeans debugger is quite lacking.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/Address
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at modules.impl.EmailModule.process(EmailModule.java:41)
    at agent.AgentDriver.callModules(AgentDriver.java:66)
    at agent.AgentDriver.process(AgentDriver.java:33)
    at agent.AgentUI.agentTextFieldActionPerformed(AgentUI.java:71)
```

Comment: Is the err on line `EmailHelper email = ...`?

Comment: That's right @Telthien - the debugger doesn't let me explore further than that.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's up here. Try making `SendEmail` static, and call it with a static reference?

Comment: I can't see your class name in the stack trace. Is it the right one? Or are you running something else?

Comment: @Telthien it doesn't need to be static.

Comment: I'm sure I'm running the correct project. What does the error mean?

Comment: I don't know. I copied your code out to a NetBeans project and it ran without errors. Try cleaning and rebuilding. If that doesn't work, redownload the JavaMail API.

Comment: No luck @Telthien. Do i maybe have to import something extra to make it work?

Comment: Have you added the JavaMail API to your project's configuration? If not, you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html)

Comment: I have not, however I have used this code in another project without it. I'll try adding

Comment: Let me know if that works. If it does, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Just tried it, made no difference

Comment: Let's move to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27264/random) (though I may not be there for very long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this actually has to do with Java EE. This solution comes from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/) and [here](http://helponjee.blogspot.com/2012/04/classformaterror-absent-code-attribute.html).

Java EE can screw up your classpath, so often it just needs to be removed and added again (or just removed). If your classpath has issues, you can occasionally get a `java.lang.ClassFormatError`, which is what happened here.